# Committing data in Excel cell using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

- A cell in Excel is filled out (by touchscreen).
- The user goes directly from the Cell to a button to print something

But when the button is pushed, the cell is still in edit mode.

How to commit the value bieng edited in the excel sheet in the button push event using google apps script?

I tried the following which doesnt work: (it jumps to another cell and sets a value, to simulate committing the current cell bieng edited)

```
input_sheet.setActiveSelection("A1:A1");
input_sheet.getRange('A1').setValue('Hello');
input_sheet.setActiveSelection("A1");
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to my knowledge to do this exactly. There are workarounds, the most popular one seems to be using an "OnEdit" function that solution is given here: [How do I deselect an active cell when clicking on an image to run a script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34050085/how-do-i-deselect-an-active-cell-when-clicking-on-an-image-to-run-a-script)