# How do I deselect an active cell when clicking on an image to run a script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet-bound script that is invoked by clicking an image in the spreadsheet. I've found that the script can be blocked if a cell that it needs to modify is active or being edited by the user.

The code could be anything, even as something as simple as this:

```js
function newf() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var range = sheet.getRange("R4");
  range.clear();
}
```

When the cell `R4` is open, the function will ignore the cell.

How do I deselect an open cell when clicking on an image to run a script?

The easy (manual) solution would be to click off the open cell prior to clicking on the image, but I am trying to make the script fool-proof and this can be a costly concern. Is there any way that the function can forcefully deselect an active cell?

Edit: I do not mean active cell. Definitely "open cell." Here are pictures of the error.

Open cell with data being entered
[image: Open cell with data being entered]

Clicked on Picture, program ran
[image: Clicked on Picture, program ran]

Comment: I suppose you want to talk about Active cell , instead of opened cell. You could use, for that, the function setActiveRange, which take a range in parameter, a range that could be the cell you want to be active. (with getRange(x,y,1,1) where (x,y) would be the coordinate of your cell).

Comment: @LMS I wish this was the solution, but the script just selects another cell, and leaves the cell entry field alone.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Sheet.setActive()` to move the attached user's cursor to a different location in the spreadsheet. You need to remember that there is a relationship between the User Interface and scripts invoked from it, which is what allows the script to determine and change the currently active cell. This does not extend to the multiple user case, though - if User1 is editing the guarded cell when User2 clicks to run the script, the script will have no idea about it.

```js
function newf() {
  var safePlace = "A1"; // Some safe cell
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var activeCell = ss.getActiveCell();
  if (activeCell.getSheet() == sheet && activeCell.getA1Notation() == "R4") 
    sheet.setActiveSelection(safePlace);
  var range = sheet.getRange("R4");
  var activeCell = ss.getActiveCell();
  if (activeCell.getA1Notation() == range.getA1Notation() && activeCell.getSheet().getName() == range.getSheet().getName()) {
    // Move user from target cell
    sheet.setActiveSelection(safePlace);
  range.clear();
}
```

Comment: Same problem as before, open cell is ignored until script is finished. This solution now places the info in the open cell into another selected "safePlace" but does not preform the function of the script.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problems, both the initial one and with the solution proposed by Mogsdad.

I resolved it the following way:

Before running any of the script, the first three lines get a different sheet opened and the spreadsheet gets flushed:

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('DIFFERENT SHEET NAME'), true);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
```

The rest of the script follows.

Then at the end of the script, I reopen the initial sheet with a simple:

```
spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('ORIGINAL SHEET NAME'), true);
```

Comment: SpreadsheetApp.flush() worked for me, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Another "solution" to this is not to use a button, but use a check mark as if it we a button, and use the onEdit function.

```
function onEdit(e)
{
 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  checkbox1 = ss.getRange("saveCheckbox_001");
  if (checkbox1.isChecked())
  {
    submit1(); //do all the fun stuff associated with this checkbox
    checkbox1.uncheck();
  }

  //more checkbox handling and calling other functions can go here if you need more than one "button"

}
```

Comment: This is good, but it would be nice if you could make the button say something other than a checkbox. So you could make it clear which button is "undo" and "enter" etc...