# Script to save cell being edited

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How can I make a script save the cell that is being edited ?
(Basically make the script press "enter" before proceeding).

I'm trying to find a fool-proof way of this being done, as this spreadsheet is meant to be used by colleagues.

I have tried `setActiveRange` / `setActiveSelection` to set another cell active, but this doesn't work (and therefore the last cell that has been edited - but not validated - is not taken into account by the script.

Same question seems to have been asked 2 years ago :
[How do I deselect an active cell when clicking on an image to run a script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34050085/how-do-i-deselect-an-active-cell-when-clicking-on-an-image-to-run-a-script)

But there's no answer.

Comment: You may want to look at [onEdit()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/spreadsheet-trigger-builder#onEdit()) the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit) gives you the old and new value of the edited cell

Comment: The referred question has an answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I deselect an active cell when clicking on an image to run a script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34050085/how-do-i-deselect-an-active-cell-when-clicking-on-an-image-to-run-a-script)