# Google-Appscript Update Cell value (press enter) via script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheet setup as a form with an image/button attached to a script. If the user clicks the button while they are editing a cell the script executes without updating the cell's value. The problem is that the user doesn't always hit "Enter" between filling out the information in the last cell and clicking the Submit button.

Is there a piece of code I can add to the script to update active cells before executing?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9cqK.png)

Comment: I've tried the onEdit() in this post and it works fine. Please check if this would be helpful to you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34050085/how-do-i-deselect-an-active-cell-when-clicking-on-an-image-to-run-a-script

Comment: The onEdit() does the trick. Its not ideal, but a helpful work around. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome! glad that i could help